# Unexpected end of input (javascript and JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to simulate a session with javascript. Mostly, saved the user credentials into the LocalStorage and compare with the array afterwards. 
I am getting an Unexpected end of input on the   `var oStoredCredentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedCredentials);`  line and i cannot find the answer..
This is the whole block of code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submitBtnLog", function(){
        var sUsername = $("#LoginName").val();
        var sPassword = $("#LoginPassword").val();

     for(var i=0; i< aEmployees.length; i++){
        if(sUsername == aEmployees[i].username && sPassword == aEmployees[i].password){
            login = true;                
            var sUsername = aEmployees[i].username;
            var sPassword = aEmployees[i].password;
            var oCredentials = {"savedUsername":sUsername,"savedPassword":sPassword};
            var sCredentials = JSON.stringify(oCredentials);
            localStorage.savedCredentials = sCredentials;

        }
    }
});
/*CHECK IF USER HAS ALREADY STARTED A "SESSION"*******************************************************************************/

if (localStorage.getItem("savedCredentials") === null) {
    localStorage.savedCredentials = [];
}else{
    var oStoredCredentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedCredentials);
    //console.dir(oStoredCredentials.savedUsername)
    for(var i=0; i< aEmployees.length; i++){
        if(oStoredCredentials.savedUsername==aEmployees[i].username && oStoredCredentials.savedPassword==aEmployees[i].password){
            login = true;
        }

    if(login === true){
                    var BoxHtml="Welcome "+aEmployees[i].name +" "+aEmployees[i].surname; 
                    $("#Navigation").css({"display":"block"});
                    $("#LoginContainer").html(BoxHtml);
    }else{
        console.log(error);
            };
     };
};
```

Comment: And what is in the `localStorage.savedCredentials`? Can you confirm the JSON is really there?

Comment: yes. I am saving the username and the password that the user inputs into a variable, i am stringifying it and save it to localstorage

Comment: I see, but if that goes wrong for some reason, the second call reading the `localStorage` will fail, no matter what you try. This question is just to assess the problem location.

Comment: I am checking if the localstorage is empty. if there is no savedCredentials variable into it, than i just declare an empty array. .

Comment: Try to indent your code right (the `if(login === true){` is inside for loop). Also you don't need to use semicolons after `if` or `for`.

Comment: You should probably use `localStorage.setItem()` for storing the storage. And then `localStorage.getItem()` to get the stored storage.

Comment: @jcubic: _"Also you don't need to use semicolons after `if` or `for`"_ is never good advice.

Comment: Also you have double initialization of `var sUsername` and `var sPassword`

Comment: @Cerbrus why? http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: @jcubic: Oh derp. Somehow, I confused semicolons with accolades. `; !== {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created some simple code of how to work with `localStorage`
Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<input id="LoginName" />
<input id="LoginPassword" />
<input id="submitBtnLog" type='button' value="Submit" />
<input id='btnGetLocalStorage' type='button' value='Get Local Storage' />
```

Here is my **Javascript** code:

```
var Credentials = {
    sUsername: '',
    sPassword: ''
}

$('#submitBtnLog').click(function(){
    Credentials.sUsername = $("#LoginName").val();
    Credentials.sPassword = $("#LoginPassword").val();
    localStorage.setItem('savedCredentials', JSON.stringify(Credentials));

});

$('#btnGetLocalStorage').click(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('savedCredentials') != null){   
        var oStoredCredentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedCredentials'));    
        alert('Username = ' + oStoredCredentials.sUsername + '    Password = ' + oStoredCredentials.sPassword);
        localStorage.removeItem('savedCredentials')
    }
});
```

Please let me know if you need some additional information of how to work with localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce your issue. It seams `localStorage.savedCredentials` stores empty array and not the stringified object, because of the `localStorage.savedCredentials = [];` line.

You should double-check your code and ensure localStorage.savedCredentials is always what you expect it to be.

Comment: I found the Issue. Apparently it doesnt set an empty array but an empty value. Instead of saving the brackets it just saves and empty space. It works fine if i say localStorage.savedCredentials = "[]";

Answer (score 0):

You are storing [] when your localStorage is null. So, when else part starts executing it takes [] as the value to be parsed and it finds difficulty in that. Change your logic of storing [] in localStorage when it is null.